# Cross-thread operation exception where shouldn't arise

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety

I have a strange `Cross-thread operation exception` on VS2013, WinForms, Debug mode when my method is called by a FileSystemWatcher event.

The exception rises on `flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();`.

The code is:

```
public void AddStrategyIcon(StrategyIcon[] icons)
{
    if (flowLayoutPanel.InvokeRequired)
        flowLayoutPanel.Invoke(new Action<StrategyIcon[]>(AddStrategyIcon),
            new object[] {icons});
    else
    {
        flowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(icons);
        flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();  // <- Cross-thread op. not valid ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas why is the exception thrown and how to fix it?

Comment: The real code should be here.

Comment: That `Invoked Thread ID 21` output is very wrong. It should have reported Thread 8. Something wrong with how/where the flowLayoutPanel is created maybe.

Comment: This is the origin of the exception, but why? It must not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found in the method argument. `StrategyIcon` is a UserControl with custom drawing.

It crashes at:

```
flowLayoutPanel.Invoke(new Action<StrategyIcon[]>(AddStrategyIcon),
    new object[] {icons});
```

The problem was fixed with changing the argument to a DTO (Data Transfer Object) and moving the actual creation of the UserControls to the view:

Working code:

```
public void AddStrategyIcon(StrategyIconDto[] dtoList)
{
    if (flowLayoutPanel.InvokeRequired)
        flowLayoutPanel.Invoke(new Action<StrategyIconDto[]>(AddStrategyIcon),
            new object[] {dtoList});
    else
    {
        var controls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (StrategyIconDto dto in dtoList)
            controls.Add((Control) new StrategyIcon(dto));

        flowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout();
        flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(controls.ToArray());
        flowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `flowLayoutPanel` is created on a thread other than the UI thread then `flowLayoutPanel.InvokeRequired` will report that a invoke is not required if it was called on the same non UI thread.

However when you call `ResumeLayout()` that ends up calling functions on the containing control who does live on the UI thread, and that raises the error.

Find where you call `flowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel()` and see if it is being called on a thread that is not the main UI thread.